# How to get the latest filename alone in a directory?

Tags: linux

I am using

```
ls -ltr /homedir/mydirectory/work/ |tail -n 1|cut -d ' ' -f 10
```

But this is a very crude way of getting the desired result.And also its unreliable.
The output I get on simply executing

```
ls -ltr /homedir/mydirectory/work/ |tail -n 1
```

is

```
-rw-r--r-- 1 user pusers 1764 Apr  1 12:06 firstfile.xml
```

So here I get the file name.
But if the output on doing the above command is like

```
-rw-r--r-- 100 user pusers 1764 Apr  1 12:06 firstfile.xml
```

the first command fails ! And understandably as I am cutting the result from the 10th character which does not hold valid now.

So how to refine it.

Comment: Does "latest" mean the file of which the modification date is the most recent?

Comment: Yes. it means that.
I want the file name alone

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Why do you use the `-l` flag for `ls` if you don't need it? Make `ls` simply output the filenames if you don't need more information instead of trying to "parse" its non-unified output (raping poor text processing utilities...).

```
LAST_MODIFIED_FILE=`ls -tr | tail -n 1`
```

Comment: But I want the filename. Thats the requirement.
So, got to use the "cut"

Comment: @R11G Nah, you don't. What do you think `ls` outputs if not filenames, seriously? Have you even tried the solution I proposed at all?

Comment: Yes. I tried that only.
The confusion I still have is like if the second column (hard link count to that file/directory) is in two/three digits - my earlier command where I am using 'cut' to get ONLY the file name  - will fail.
How to overcome that?

Comment: @R11G If all you need is the filename, then my code will work.

Answer (score 1):

If you really want to achieve this using your method, then, use **awk** instead of **cut**

```
ls -ltr /var/log/ |tail -n 1| awk '{print $9}'
```

Answer (score 1):

Extended user user529758 answer which can give result as per file name

use below commnad as per the file name

```
ls -tr Filename* | tail -n 1
```